# Put an existing file into a SharePoint 2016 document library via SSIS

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis

I would like to put an existing file into an existing SharePoint 2016 document library via SSIS.I have tried the examples below with no success.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237700/c-rest-add-file-to-sharepoint-library
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a879dc3c-80e8-487c-a909-69b75993fc2a/upload-data-file-into-sharepoint-web-site-using-ssis-script-task-approach?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

I don’t need to use a Script task if there is a better transformation. 
I don’t want to use a 3rd party tool.
I can't set up email on the library.

I would to hear how others are doing this and a working example would be much 
appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this from SSIS?  You can use the HttpClient Upload() method from either c# or VB.Net.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am building the file dynamically from different sources via SSIS. I will look into HttpClient although my initial tests show that I have HttpClientConnection instead. If you know of working examples that would help greatly as most of the examples I see are asking why they do not work. Thank you.

Comment: My point is having a c# application you do not need a SQL Server Integration Services to do the upload.  The same upload commands can be used in the c# code.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thank you. I do understand your point. To me building an external application is no different than me using a 3rd party tool. Thank you for the example(s).

Comment: A do not consider in this case SSIS a third party tool.  third party tools normally reduce the number of lines of code you have to write.  So you would send one command to a 3rd party tool and it would execute 100 instructions reducing the number of lines of code.  In this case you are writing the same code in SSIS that you can write in c# with the same number of lines.  Calling SSIS is just adding another unnecessary layer to your code which in my opinion which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Sharepoint Adaptor to achieve this using Data flow task

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SSISDataFlowSourceDestinationforSharePoint

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I do not want to use 3rd party tools.